# Unable to execute single tc, login then run other application features, right now its running as a suite

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, java, test-automation-framework, testng

I have to execute my test cases as a single as well as a suite, right now its running as a suite but not as a single test case in selenium webdriver: Below is my test which are calling methods present in business class, and business class calling page class containing locators: Below is my test of one report, same way we have to create different reports:

**Business class:**

```
    package com.deere.gmsr.business;
    import org.openqa.selenium.By;
    import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
    import org.openqa.selenium.support.CacheLookup;
    import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
    import org.openqa.selenium.support.How;
    import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
    import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
    import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

    import com.deere.gmsr.page.MhCurrentMonthReportPage;
    import com.deere.gmsr.utility.PageUtility;
    import com.deere.gmsr.utility.ScreenshotUtility;

    public class MhCurrentMonthReportBusiness extends MhCurrentMonthReportPage {

        private WebDriver driver;
        //WaitUtility waitutility;

        public MhCurrentMonthReportBusiness(WebDriver driver) {
            super(driver);
            this.driver=driver;

        }

        public void clickToCreateNewButton() throws Exception {

            //  WaitUtility.waitForElement(createNewButton);
            //  WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver,10);
            //  WebElement createNewButton=wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementIfVisible(By.xpath(PageUtility.CREATE_NEW_BUTTON_XPATH)));
            //  WebElement createNewButton=wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(PageUtility.CREATE_NEW_BUTTON_XPATH)));
                Thread.sleep(3000);
                createNewButton.click();
                System.out.println("fffff");
                ScreenshotUtility.captureScreenShot(this.driver);
            } 

        public void selectEquipmentDivision() {

             Select equipmentDivisionDropdown=new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath(PageUtility.SELECT_EQUIPMENT_DIVISION)));
             equipmentDivisionDropdown.selectByIndex(1);
             System.out.println(equipmentDivisionDropdown.getFirstSelectedOption());    
            }
        public void openLocation() throws Exception{
            Thread.sleep(3000);

               openLocationPopup.click();
        }

    public void selectGeography() throws Exception {

            Select selectGeographyType=new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath(PageUtility.SELECT_GEAOGRAPHY_TYPE)));
            selectGeographyType.selectByIndex(1);
            Thread.sleep(3000);
            clickOnGreaterThanSign.click();
            clickOnNextLevel.click();
            clickToUS.click();
            clickOnSaveButton.click();


        }

    public void selectMarketSegment() throws Exception {

        Thread.sleep(3000);
        clickOnSelectButton.click();
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        clickOnAuction.click();
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        save1.click();

        }

    public void openProductWindow() throws Exception {
        //  WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver,30);
        //  WebElement openProductPopup=wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(PageUtility.OPEN_PRODUCT_POPUP)));
            Thread.sleep(3000);
            openProductPopup.click();
            selectProduct.click();
            clickOnProductSaveButton.click();
        }

        public void selectHistoryReports() throws Exception {
        //  selectHistoryReports.isSelected();
            Thread.sleep(3000);
            selectHistoryReports.click();

            Thread.sleep(1000);
            //WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver,15);
            //WebElement selectMonthly=wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(selectMonthly));
            selectMonthly.click();      
        }

        public void selectTimePeriod(){
            Select currentMonth= new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath(PageUtility.SELECT_TIMEPERIOD)));
            currentMonth.selectByVisibleText("Current Month");
        }

        public void clickOnViewReport() throws Exception {
            Thread.sleep(7000);
            WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver,20);
            WebElement clickOnViewReportButton=wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(PageUtility.CLICK_ON_VIEWREPORT_BUTTON)));
            clickOnViewReportButton.click();
        }


        public void clearSelections() {
            clearSelections.click();

        }

        public void clickOnHomeIcon() {
            homeIcon.click();

        }

        public void scrollUp(){
            ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("scroll(0, -250);");
        }

    }
```

**TestCase Class:**

```
        package com.deere.gmsr.testcase; 
        import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;
        import org.testng.Assert;
        import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
        import org.testng.annotations.Test;
        import com.deere.gmsr.business.MhCurrentMonthReportBusiness;
        import com.deere.gmsr.driver.Driver;

    public class MhCurrentMonthReportTest {

        public MhCurrentMonthReportBusiness mhCurrentMonthReportBusiness;


        public MhCurrentMonthReportTest() throws Exception {

        mhCurrentMonthReportBusiness = PageFactory.initElements(Driver.getDriver(), MhCurrentMonthReportBusiness.class);

        }



        @Test(priority=8)
        public void CurrentMonthReport() throws Exception{      
            mhCurrentMonthReportBusiness.clickToCreateNewButton();
            mhCurrentMonthReportBusiness.selectEquipmentDivision();
            mhCurrentMonthReportBusiness.openLocation();
            mhCurrentMonthReportBusiness.selectGeography();
            mhCurrentMonthReportBusiness.selectMarketSegment();
            mhCurrentMonthReportBusiness.openProductWindow();
            mhCurrentMonthReportBusiness.selectHistoryReports();
            mhCurrentMonthReportBusiness.selectTimePeriod();
            mhCurrentMonthReportBusiness.scrollUp();

            mhCurrentMonthReportBusiness.clickOnViewReport();
            Thread.sleep(3000);
            mhCurrentMonthReportBusiness.clickOnHomeIcon();
    //      Driver.getDriver().navigate().back();
    //      mhCurrentMonthReportBusiness.clearSelections();
            Assert.assertTrue(true);

        }

    }
```

**Loginbusiness Class:**

```
    package com.deere.gmsr.business;
    import java.util.Properties;

    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

    import com.deere.gmsr.page.LoginPage;
    import com.deere.gmsr.utility.Constant;
    import com.deere.gmsr.utility.ScreenshotUtility;
    import com.deere.gmsr.utility.Utility;

    public class LoginBusiness  {

        private WebDriver driver;
        LoginPage loginPage;
        public LoginBusiness(WebDriver driver) throws Exception {
            this.driver = driver;
            loginPage = new LoginPage(driver);

        }

    //  public LoginDTO getLoginCredentials() throws Exception {
    //      Properties properties = Utility.getproperties(Constant.CONFIGURATION_PROPERTIES_FILE_PATH);
    //      String userName = properties.getProperty(Constant.USERNAME);
    //      String password = properties.getProperty(Constant.PASSWORD);
    //      LoginDTO loginDTO = new LoginDTO();
    //      loginDTO.setUserName(userName);
    //      loginDTO.setPassword(password);
    //      return loginDTO;
    //  }

        public void loginToApplication() throws Exception {
            loginPage.getUserNameTextField().clear();
            Properties properties = Utility.getproperties(Constant.CONFIGURATION_PROPERTIES_FILE_PATH);
            String username = properties.getProperty(Constant.USERNAME);
            loginPage.getUserNameTextField().sendKeys(username);
            String password = properties.getProperty(Constant.PASSWORD);
            loginPage.getPasswordTextField().clear();
        //  ScreenshotUtility.captureScreenShot(driver);
            loginPage.getPasswordTextField().sendKeys(password);

            loginPage.getSignInButton().click();

        }

    }
```

**Login testclass:**

```
    public class LoginTest{

        public LoginBusiness loginBusiness;
        public LoginTest() throws Exception {
            loginBusiness = new LoginBusiness(Driver.getDriver());
        }

    @Test
        public void loginToGmsrApplication() throws Exception {

    loginBusiness.loginToApplication();



        }
```

**Driver class**

```
package com.deere.gmsr.driver;

import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterSuite;

import com.deere.gmsr.utility.Constant;
import com.deere.gmsr.utility.Message;
import com.deere.gmsr.utility.Utility;

import io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager;

public class Driver {

    private static WebDriver driver;
    private Driver() {

    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public static synchronized WebDriver getDriver() throws Exception {

        if (null == driver) {
            Properties properties = Utility.getproperties(Constant.CONFIGURATION_PROPERTIES_FILE_PATH);
            String browser = properties.getProperty(Constant.BROWSER);
            String url = properties.getProperty(Constant.URL);
            switch (browser) {
            case Constant.CHROME:
                WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
            //  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\chromedriver\\chromedriver.exe");
            //  WebDriverManager.chromedriver().version(Constant.CHROME_DRIVER_VERSION).setup();
                driver = new ChromeDriver();
                // System.out.println(WebDriverManager.chromedriver().getVersions());
                break;
            case Constant.IE:
                WebDriverManager.iedriver().setup();
                // WebDriverManager.iedriver().version(Constant.IE_DRIVER_VERSION).setup();
                driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
                break;
            case Constant.FIREFOX:
                WebDriverManager.firefoxdriver().setup();
                // WebDriverManager.firefoxdriver().version(Constant.FIREFOX_DRIVER_VERSION).setup();
                driver = new FirefoxDriver();
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println(Message.SUITABLE_DRIVER_NOT_FOUND);
                break;

            }
            if (driver != null) {
                driver.manage().window().maximize();
                driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();

                driver.get(url);
                driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            }



        }

        return driver;

    }

    public void navigateBack(){
        driver.navigate().back();
    }

    @AfterSuite
    public void quitDriver() {
        if (null != driver) {

            driver.quit();
        }
    }

}
```

---

- ### List item

---

How to use this in our code so that we can successfully call login method for individual test cases as well as a suite.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Can you fix the formatting and explain how you are running?

Comment: I am unable to do formatting I believe I dont have rights, LoginTest is calling login business and here we have written Driver.getDriver() which is calling Driver class(have all the drivers) and next test cases we have mhCurrentMonthReportTest which is calling Business class, I have added mhCurrentMonthReportBusiness and Driver class

Comment: You always have the permissions needed to edit your own posts. You should also consider paring down the example to closer to a _minimum_ working example since right now it's a huge amount of code, including obviously irrelevant content such as commented-out code. This will make it easier for people to read your question to provide an answer.

Answer (score 0):

May this help you, just replace your test case class like this:-

```
    public class MhCurrentMonthReportTest extends LoginTest {

            public MhCurrentMonthReportBusiness mhCurrentMonthReportBusiness;


            public MhCurrentMonthReportTest() throws Exception {

            mhCurrentMonthReportBusiness = PageFactory.initElements(driver, MhCurrentMonthReportBusiness.class);

            }



            @Test(priority=2)
            public void CurrentMonthReport() throws Exception{ 

             //Your test steps
             }
}
```

and your LoginTest Class like this:-

```
  public class LoginTest{
    WebDriver driver;
          @BeforeClass
          public void launchApplication()
            {
               driver =Driver.getDriver();
             }

        @Test(priority=1)
            public void loginToGmsrApplication() throws Exception {
    public LoginBusiness loginBusiness= new LoginBusiness(driver);
        loginBusiness.loginToApplication();

            }
```

In this once you execute your test class then before your test class method's only once your login method will execute and after that all test method will execute which are in ReportTest class.

Now create XML file like this and run this:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="TestSuite" parallel="classes" thread-count="4">
<test name="Test 1">
<classes>
<class name="com.deere.gmsr.testcase.MhCurrentMonthReportTest">
</class>
</classes>
</test> 
</suite>
```

Comment: Do I need to make changes in every test cases

Comment: Yes, just change your LoginTest class and ``extends`` this class in your all test class

Comment: first make sure is it working for u?

Comment: I am only able to login nothing else is working now, my concerned is it should login then move to next page accept conditions, and then create new report

Comment: And now its not working as a Test suite,typing two times both username and password.

Comment: this will only work when your test class's page is present just after the application login.

Comment: if it's not then just design your test case like this that it may able to reached that page after login.

Comment: r u trying to run parallel test?

Comment: hmmm.. its working for only one username and password.. If I want to execute as a single tc then I have to import that page test case into MHCurrentReport test case.?

Comment: for parallel run or login with multiple users you need to make some changes.